# Dynamic interpolate / generate gql mutation query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

Sample JavaScript code that uses apollo-client on the frontend:

```
function getGql(newVersion) {
  return gql`
      mutation TestMutation(
          $name: String!
          ${(newVersion)?`$format: Boolean`:``}
      ) {
          testMutation(
              name: $name
              ${(newVersion)?`format: $format`:``}
          )
      }
  `;
}
```

**Question:** Can I interpolate `gql-tag` query so that the above method evaluates to either:

```
gql`
      mutation TestMutation(
          $name: String!
          $format: Boolean
      ) {
          testMutation(
              name: $name
              format: $format
          )
      }
  `;
```

or:

```
gql`
      mutation TestMutation(
          $name: String!
      ) {
          testMutation(
              name: $name
          )
      }
  `;
```

...based on the boolean parameter to `getGql()`?

Comment: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec--include

Comment: @xadm `@include(if: $someTest)` is for the response from the GQL server, right? It also gets sent to the GQL backend. In my above example, the GQL request is not yet made.

Comment: no need to use string manipulations/template literals (abusing) with graphql while it is [natively] supported

Comment: @xadm `@include(if: $someTest)` is NOT supported for parameters to the mutation. You can use it for e.g., `fields`

Comment: aaaa, args .... still no need to use it ... it is nulklable, simply don't pass it ... passed, used, not passed, not used, ... no need to "polish it", just/always define type arg, pass variable when required